# VERP is visible in CiviMail sender address

Tags: civimail

When sending out CiviMail mailings, the unique VERP address is listed as the sender address.  As I understand, VERP should be invisible and should instead show the FROM address set in both Administer>CiviMail>From Email Addresses and in Administer>System Settings>Outbound Email.

We have bluehost, and I know that it doesn't support VERP, so instead we have a catch-all bounce email address (via google app using our domain name), and the bounces seem to work just fine, except that the VERP sender address is visible.

Comment: Suggest posting your mail headers to help others see what you're seeing. Please format them nicely with the `{}` button :)

Comment: Did you figure this one out? I'm having a similar problem with civimail.

Comment: Basically, our shared hosting on Bluehost cannot handle CiviMail and its bounce system.

Answer (score 2):

Bluehost appears to restrict outbound emails to the list of email addresses configured on your Bluehost account.

Since dynamically generated VERP address format emails won't exist in this list, Bluehost is unlikely to correctly handle outbound dynamic VERP addresses.

You might get more informed and informative responses if you include a bit more debug information to better describe the issue you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to send the emails? 
The smtp server at bluehost?
Some mail servers rewrite the message to put the smtp enveloppe as the sender instead of what you put in the from header.

Try to switch from mail() to smtp() or the other way around, it might solve your problem

X+

Comment: We are using mail() to send the emails from our google apps email account. The test emails from the Settings>Outbound Mail page are functioning correctly and sending from the correct email address.  But mailings through CiviMail do not show the correct sender email address.

I will see if setting up smtp changes anything.

Comment: Trying to set mail to SMTP is creating more problems than it is solving.  Any other ideas?

Comment: If you use google app with your domain name, you do not need catchall. You'll need to describe in detail your setting and what you put in the various fields (eg bounce mail, what email you see for the verp as the sender...), so we can properly understand your setup